# Wide top navigation menu -- li won't wrap

Tags: html, css, word-wrap, nav

I'm a long time developer, but new to Bootstrap.  I am working on a top nav for a website that has 6+ items horizontal and numerous links in dropdown menus. I have everything working, but I cannot get the main menu items to wrap with smaller screen sizes.  No matter what I've tried, the overflow goes offscreen.  Thanks.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm flex-row">
    <a href="#"><img src="#" style="width: 250px; height: auto; margin: 0 3rem;" /></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle catogary" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">WHO WE ARE</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu single" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <ul class="nav flex-column">
                                    <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Link</a> </li>
                                    <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link i" href="#">Link</a> </li>
                                    <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link i" href="#">Link</a> </li>
                                    <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link i" href="#">Link</a> </li>
                                    <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link i" href="#">Link</a> </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle catogary" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">PRODUCTS</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu mega" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <ul class="nav flex-column">
                                <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Object 1</a> </li>
                                <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link i" href="#">Item 1</a> </li>
                                <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link i" href="#">Item 2</a> </li>
                                <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link i" href="#">Item 3</a> </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <ul class="nav flex-column">
                                <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Object 2</a> </li>
                                <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link i" href="#">Item 1</a> </li>
                                <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link i" href="#">Item 2</a> </li>
                                <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link i" href="#">Item 3</a> </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <ul class="nav flex-column">
                                <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Object 3</a> </li>
                                <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link i" href="#">Item 1</a> </li>
                                <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link i" href="#">Item 2</a> </li>
                                <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link i" href="#">Item 3</a> </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <ul class="nav flex-column">
                                <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Object 4</a> </li>
                                <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link i" href="#">Item 1</a> </li>
                                <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link i" href="#">Item 2</a> </li>
                                <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link i" href="#">Item 3</a> </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">PROJECTS</a></li>

            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle catogary" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">DESIGN TOOLS</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu mega" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <ul class="nav flex-column">
                                <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Object 1</a> </li>
                                <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link i" href="#">Item 1</a> </li>
                                <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link i" href="#">Item 2</a> </li>
                                <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link i" href="#">Item 3</a> </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <ul class="nav flex-column">
                                <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Object 2</a> </li>
                                <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link i" href="#">Item 1</a> </li>
                                <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link i" href="#">Item 2</a> </li>
                                <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link i" href="#">Item 3</a> </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <ul class="nav flex-column">
                                <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Object 3</a> </li>
                                <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link i" href="#">Item 1</a> </li>
                                <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link i" href="#">Item 2</a> </li>
                                <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link i" href="#">Item 3</a> </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <ul class="nav flex-column">
                                <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Object 4</a> </li>
                                <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link i" href="#">Item 1</a> </li>
                                <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link i" href="#">Item 2</a> </li>
                                <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link i" href="#">Item 3</a> </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">CATALOGS</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>

        </ul>

    </div>
</nav>
```

[CodePen HTML with CSS and Script](https://codepen.io/doncroy/pen/qBNbwja)

Comment: It wouldnt wrap the nav, but it will solve the problem. You could set the font-size on like 1.5vw. So the font will be small enough to fit the screen everytime.

Comment: I found it... should anyone want to use the code.  `code`.navbar ul {float: left; display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;}

Comment: I've rolled back your edit adding an answer in your question. I'm glad you found a solution to your problem. However, an actual answer/solution should **not** be edited into your Question. In general, you should [edit] the Question to *clarify the Question*, but not to include an Answer within the Question. You should create your own Answer with the code you used to solve your problem, then accept it (the system may require a 48-hour delay prior to accepting your own answer).